# print out generated HTML with WebView

Tags: javascript, html, swift

I want to get the html source of a website which content is partially generated by javascript.

I use Xcode 9.2 and Swift 4 and I'm coding for macOS.

My idea is to add a WebKit View to my storyboard and read out the read out the desired id with javascript.

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('player').innerHTML.toString()", completionHandler: {(html: Any?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        print(html)
    })

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.navigationDelegate = self

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwY6doa-0Bg")
    let urlreq = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webView.load(urlreq)
}
}
```

Unfortunately the output still doesn't contain the generated HTML source.
Do you have any Idea how I can proceed?

Comment: I'm looking for same, Have you found any solution ?